# Java: Concurrency with three level users

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

How can I implement a service (class) where there are three level of users (threads) that access to it with a different priority?

- threads lv1: priority over all; when they use the service, no other user is allowed
- threads lv2: priority over lv3
- threads lv3: normal users

Ideally,

- main() : start threads
- service() : coordinate access to some data
- users : request access to the data, use it, release the access

Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: can u share some code u tried

Comment: I think your priority levels contradict between 1 and 2. How can lv1 have "priority over all", when the explicit case for lv2 is to have "priority over lv1"? This seems like a deadlock would result

Comment: @EvanBechtol: sorry I meant lv3; fixed

Comment: I have tried to code it, but I can't make it to work (deadlocks); I'm just setting a lock and a condition on each user and when they ask for request the service has a queue to each service (ie 5 queues) and checks it; if busy, gets the queue of the user and puts it in wait

Comment: @fawim post this code please.

Comment: I don't want you to fix my code, I'm asking for good ways to do it - even pseudo codes or ideas are fine

Comment: ‎Your problem description is very vague. It is not clear what the resource is, what the threads that "use it" actually do, and how the flow of work is supposed to look like. That's why people are asking for code - it makes the use case more concrete. So please make your question *answerable* by providing some code - like classes, services etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're right; I will describe it better next time. I'm for now fine with the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve level exclusivity using three [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)s, one for each level.

Level-3 users would use a read lock on the `level3Lock`.

Level-2 users would use a write lock on the `level3Lock` and a read lock on the `level2Lock` - no level 3 user will have access while a level-2 user is working on the data.

Level-1 users would continue the tradition and write lock both the level-3 and level-2 locks.

However - this only implements exclusivity. If you really want priority functionality you could control access using a queue - a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is an obvious choice. A correctly set up `Executor` would then process tasks from that queue.

Comment: I like it! (you just swapped lv2 with lv3, but that's ok, I like the idea)